# Need to set charset to UTF-8 in Google (Chrome) devtools

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to change to charset from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in Chrome devtools via the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
> var el = $('meta[charset="ISO-8859-1"]');
<- undefined
> el
<- <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
> el.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
> el
<- <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

On the elements panel, you'll see the attribute value update immediately.

`$()` is DevTools' shortcut for `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: After `> var el = $('meta[charset="ISO-8859-1"]');
<- undefined` when I type `el`, I get `null`. Then typing `el.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');` results in `TypeError: el is null`. Both Chrome and Firefox. Using Ubuntu 18.04, latest updates of browsers.